# Django Client().login() creates Anonymous user even when returning True

Tags: django, django-views, django-testing, django-middleware

I am writing Django tests for views and have run into a problem where Client().login(...) returns True but creates AnonymousUsers, which have no attributes.

First, I create the user in a test mixin class like :

```
@classmethod
def setUpTestData(cls):
    super(BareSetupClass, cls).setUpTestData()
    cls.regular_user = User.objects.create(email='test_user@test.com',
        first_name='test', last_name='user', confirmed_email=True
    )
    cls.regular_user.set_password("password")
    cls.regular_user.save()
```

Then I login in the test class like so:

```
class UserGroupViewTestSuite(BareSetupClass):

@classmethod
def setUpTestData(cls):
    super(UserGroupViewTestSuite, cls).setUpTestData()

    cls.user = Client()
    cls.user.login(username="test_user@test.com", password="password")
```

I have checked the value returned by calling login and it is True but the user I get from Client is still AnonymousUser, which inhibits my views from functioning properly. Thank you ahead of time!

Comment: The way you are using `Client` looks very strange. `Client()` does not return a `user` object - why are you assigning it to `cls.user`? Also why are you initialising the user as a class variable (this seems very likely to cause problems if multiple instances of that class exist)? Also how is your `cls.user` being used in tests?

Comment: Not to mention, the db is flushed after every test method, so there's no point creating data in setUpClass; it should be done in setUp.